# Why is the date being incorrectly converted?

Tags: java, date, formatting

I'm trying to convert a String date into a Date object like this:

```
  DateFormat formatter ; 
  Date date ; 
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
```

[Source](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml)

However for some reason, the month is being converted into january always.

Example inputted date: 18/08/2012
Outputted date: Wed Jan 18 00:08:00 CET 2012

Does anyone know why this is happening please?

Comment: `mm` is minutes. `MM` is months. (As documented)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"` (upper case `M`). Lower case `m` is for minutes.

Take a look at the table in [`SimpleDateFormat` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).